# How to prevent infinite loop in Boolean while loop?

Tags: while-loop, boolean, infinite-loop

I have code that goes like:

```
maybeYes = raw_input("Please enter Yes to continue.")
    if maybeYes != "Yes":
        print "Try again."
        # ask for input again
    else:
        pass
```

What do I fill in where I want to make it ask for input again?

Comment: I guess by this line - "will give you reputation" , you trying to say ..."will increase your reputation as a questioner on SO and not in points"

Answer (score 2):

you should just do the raw_input directly in a loop.

```
while True:
    result = raw_input("...")
    if result != "Yes":
        print "Try again."
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

This will loop printing `wrong` until the user types `yes`, `Yes`, `YEs`, `YES`, `yEs` or `yeS` as the input is converted to all uppercase before checking against `YES`, then your code can continue on...

```
while raw_input("Please enter Yes to start: ").upper() != 'YES':
       print 'Wrong'

print 'Correct'

#Carry on here
```

Output:

```
Please enter Yes to start: nowg
Wrong
Please enter Yes to start: wggwe
Wrong
Please enter Yes to start: Yes
Correct
```

Comment: Don't know why this has been down voted, not only is it correct it's cleaner and more robust than the other 2 current answers?

Comment: May be because people started loving downvoting.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you WANT an infinite loop here.

```
maybeYes = raw_input("Please enter Yes to continue.")
while maybeYes != "Yes":
    maybeYes = raw_input("Please try again.")
```

However, you can always add a counter/escape.

```
maybeYes = raw_input("Please enter Yes to continue.")
attempts = 0
while maybeYes != "Yes" and attempts < 10:
    maybeYes = raw_input("Please try again.")
    attempts += 1
```